# Performance hit with binary literals in Java 6 as compared to Java 7

Tags: java, binary, java-7, java-6

I am reading a book , it says

Before Java 7 , if you want to convert a binary literal in Integer.

you need to write

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("1100110", 2);
```

but after Java 7

```
int x = 0b1100110;
```

Java6 practise gives

1) There is a performance hit for that method call. -> JVM does inline expansion and other optimizations also .

2) It's really verbose. -> what this point means ?

3) It makes life hard for JIT. -> how ? I don't see any reason

Sorry but i didn't get , what these three points means ?
Can someone please explain or redirect me to some link where i can know about it ?

Comment: In java 6 I would mentally convert to hex which has no runtime overhead. `int x = 0x66;`

Comment: For me, hexidecimal is a binary format. There is no direct support for binary so I didn't use it in Java 6. Note: Java 7 is about to be EOL, so perhaps it is time to move on to Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you call `Integer.parse`, the conversion of binary string representation is done at runtime, so some CPU cycles are spent to do it; When you use a binary constant, the conversion is done at compile time, so there is no performance hit.
2. Method call takes more characters to write than the `0b` prefix, so it is more verbose.
3. JIT will have harder time figuring out the value of `x` when you use `parse`, so it wouldn't be able to mitigate the first issue, at least not easily.

It goes without saying that all of these points are about a micro-optimization, and that it is hard to imagine a situation when it would make a palpable difference.

Comment: how JIT will have harded time , I mean isn't the 3rd point and 1st point are same ?

Comment: @AdonSmith I think the third point is there to counter the argument "JIT will make sure that there is no difference". JIT may figure it out, but again it would be done at the expense of additional CPU cycles.

Comment: ok, you mean JIT may do inline expansions , but it will happen at a cost of CPU cycles.

Comment: @AdonSmith Yes, essentially, no matter what JIT does, it costs CPU cycles at runtime, vs. a numeric constant, which has zero additional cost.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is a performance hit for that method call. -> JVM does inline expansion and other optimizations also .

yes JIT is runtime feature. even if its inlined compilation is costly.

2) It's really verbose. -> what this point means ?

3) It makes life hard for JIT. -> how ? I don't see any reason

the things tht can be computed in static compile time is done in runtime. so its costly and expressed with more data than needed.